# Parse string data according to template in qt c++

Tags: c++, string, qt, parsing

I have a string which consist of data along with spaces i want to sort this string into particular variables

eg.

"  Company Name   : ABC          Department      : TESTING";

i want to split this string and get the company name and department name to add to their particular variable

Comment: Check out `QTextStream`, as well as `QString::split`. If it is already a string, and it looks like you want to split it, then you should probably indeed simply split it.

Comment: For that simple data, you don't want anything fancy like some textual template of the format. Just split it to `QStringList` and assign the parts into final variables directly with C++ code.

Comment: their are multiple spaces in this string but i am unable to display it

Comment: and my prblm for splitting is with ' ABC Department' this part

Comment: `QStringList` can split by string or by regular expression (I'm 99% sure, didn't check docs just now).  So splitting by something like regexp / *: */ should do it.

Answer (score 0):

You will have a pain in the neck for achieving that taks because the data is ill formatted,

your goal is to obtain from the string something like:

Company Name = ABC
Department = TESTING

even using the method split, you need a token that you dont have...

the suggestion i can provide is to redefine those strings in something well formatted and parsable... json is a good candidate for this task

imagine this example using json objects:

```
QString str3 = "{\"Company Name\" : \"ABC\", \"Department\" : \"TESTING\", \"Number\" : 123, \"Updated\" : false}";
```

then you need to "parse" the string into a json object, then get those "values" for the "keys"

like:

```
QJsonDocument doc1 = QJsonDocument::fromJson(str3.toUtf8());
QJsonValue company = doc1["Company Name"];
QJsonValue dept = doc1["Department"];
QJsonValue number = doc1["Number"];
QJsonValue updated = doc1["Updated"];


qDebug()<< "Company: " << company.toString();
qDebug()<< "Department: " << dept.toString();
qDebug()<< "Number: " << number.toInt();
qDebug()<< "Updated: " << updated.toBool();
```

---

your output will look like:

```
Company:  "ABC"
Department:  "TESTING"
Number:  123
Updated:  false
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response my prblm is solved from your  valuable response